# Tool to analyse and explain python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning programming Python by reading the book *Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner*. As I get further into it, I find it harder and harder to follow.

I wondered if there is a tool that is able to run any Python code I create, which steps through each line and explains what's going on?

There is one at http://pythontutor.com/ but it's only online and, as a result (I think) I can't get input function to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ipdb
ipdb.set_trace()
```

And go through your code)

Or you can use pudb with more graphic - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb

Comment: While I agree that using the debugger (ipdb or pdb) might help in seeing what a program does, it doesn't do much in terms of **"explaining** what's going on".

Comment: Thanks guys! When i said explaining, i meant showing at what point the parameter is assigned the value and the like. Will Pudb do that? Thanks for the quickk replies btw!

Comment: I'm disappointed that no one has yet found an offline equivalent (or better) to what the online python tutor offers. Are we really come to the point where the best functionality is found only online?

Comment: @lazyr Maybe we just don't need such thing?)

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself an IDE, I use Pycharm, then you can step through line by line all you want.

[Pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

> Fine-tune Python or Django applications and unit tests using a full-featured debugger with breakpoints, stepping, frames view, watches & evaluate expressions.

Stepping through code in debug view is invaluable. Sure, you can do it in other ways but you get a 30 day free trial on this s/w to see if you like it.

There are other similar packages available of course.

Comment: I agree, an IDE really is best is the long term, although I prefer PyDev, and its free...